# Combining Dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames, A and B, which both contain the same columns.

```
A = person, place
     1    ,   2
     1    ,   3

B = person, place
     2    ,   4
     2    ,   3
```

I want to combine both tables into one.

```
NewTable = person, place
           1    ,   2
           1    ,   3
           2    ,   4
           2    ,   3
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: Take a look at `?rbind`

Comment: If there are multiple datasets, place them in a list and use `do.call(rbind, yourlist)` or `rbindlist(yourlist)` from `data.table`

Comment: Thanks guys, I was getting the error "names do not match previous names." But that was because the names of the columns did not match. @akrun, that was exactly what I needed!

Comment: with `rbindlist` it won't be a problem.  It would be take the names of the first list element assuming that the columns are in order